# Databinding repeater makes the Repeater load all items twice

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, repeater

I have a repeater on which I bind a list with 3 items. The databind() is called once, I have checked this using the debugger. I have some strange behavior here because the Repeater seems to walk through this list of items twice. Instead of the 3 items, I see the repeater bind everything twice.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Load event of the Page control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sitecore.Data.Items.Item contextItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField thisSnippets = contextItem.Fields["snippets"];
        List<Item>thisSnippetItems = thisSnippets.GetItems().ToList<Item>();

        if (thisSnippetItems.Count > 0)
        {
            rptListRenderer.DataSource = thisSnippetItems;
            rptListRenderer.DataBind();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the ItemDataBound event of the rptListRenderer control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void rptListRenderer_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            Item dataItem = (Item)e.Item.DataItem;

            System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder phLiContent = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("phLiContent");

            if (phLiContent != null)
            {
                Sitecore.Data.Items.DeviceItem listItemDevice = Sitecore.Context.Database.Resources.Devices["List item"];
                RenderingReference[] renderings = dataItem.Visualization.GetRenderings(listItemDevice, false);

                foreach (RenderingReference rendering in renderings)
                {
                    string strDataSource = dataItem.ID.ToString();
                    rendering.Settings.DataSource = strDataSource;

                    Sublayout thisControl = (Sublayout)rendering.RenderingItem.GetControl(rendering.Settings);           

                    if (blockCounter == 0)
                    {
                        thisControl.Parameters = "class=snippetColHomeFirst";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        thisControl.Parameters = "class=";
                    }

                    phLiContent.Controls.Add(thisControl);

                    blockCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
```

repeater html:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="hpSnippetList.ascx.cs" Inherits="Snippets.Sublayouts.hpSnippetList" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sc" Namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" %>
<asp:repeater id="rptListRenderer" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" EnableViewState="false">
 <itemtemplate>
   <asp:placeholder id="phLiContent" runat="server" />
 </itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Any suggestions on how this can be solved? 
Page load is called only once, databind() is only called once.

Comment: paste your repeater html as well

Comment: *Instead of the 3 items, I see the repeater bind everything twice* - What do you mean by that? You get 6 elements in your repeater?

Comment: I get 3 elements in my repeater, then i see -using the debugger- that the control's code is being called. After that the repeater repeaters the 3 items again, so the itemlist consist out of 3 items, but they get processed twice...

Comment: So you say you get elements in the repeater *before* the Page_Load is being called? That's strange. I still suspect your code is being called twice. Try narrowing down your problem, remove extra code until you have an example as simple as possible and, if you still don't figure out the problem yourself, come back here with the simpler sample.

Comment: My page load is being called once. After the databind I see that it's processing the repeater_itemdatabound method. After the method has been called and processed the 3 items, I see that the repeater_databound method is called again with the same items.

Comment: OK, now I finally understand. Your `ItemDataBound` event is triggered twice, while `Page_Load` is only called once. Still, try to simplify your code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you called DataBind method in one of the control's parents. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d.aspx (DataBind docs):

> When called on a server control, this
>   method resolves all data-binding
>   expressions in the server control and
>   in any of its child controls.

Comment: I couldn't find any DataBind methods being called in one of the control's parents. I find this strange behavior :/.

Comment: @Younes The user control that contains your repeater may be inside of a control that does data binding automatically, so you might not see an explicit call to .DataBind().

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you should check for `!Page.IsPostBack` when binding things in `Page_Load`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Sitecore.Data.Items.Item contextItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        // ... the rest of the code
    }
}
```

This might solve your current problem.

Comment: Page load is only called once, so it's not this. But I will add this one just to be sure.