# Repeater control in DataView is being bound twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, repeater, nested-repeater

In an `ASP.Net 4.0` web forms based application I have a products listing page which displays list of products in a `DevExress`' `ASPxDataView`. To show all the sizes of the product there is a repeater control which is bound for each product in `ItemDataBound` event of products list.

Now the issue is that for some reason size repeater is bound twice due to which `ItemDataBound` is being called twice i.e. if there are 3 products and each product has two sizes then `ItemDataBound` is called 12 times instead of 6.

I have checked that in the code the `repeater`'s `DataBind` is called only once and `PageLoad` event is also being called only once.

What could be the reason that repeater control is bound twice?

Comment: Can we see your `ItemDataBound` method?

Comment: May be that dataSource has duplicate rows.

Comment: The ASPxDataView isn't by any chance databound twice?

Comment: i have found out a way out is that I am just setting DataSource to the repeater control in products list's ItemDataBound and not call DataBind()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Databinding repeater makes the Repeater load all items twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699037/databinding-repeater-makes-the-repeater-load-all-items-twice)